# How to change the color of an object using the timeline?

Tags: animation, materials, color, timeline

I’m trying to assign specific colors to a certain moment on the timeline.

For example:

- From 0-50 I want Red,
- From 50-75 pink,
- From 75-85 orange,
- From 85-95 gold,
- From 95-100 purple.

Comment: Probably easiest to follow the first part of [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmzAbeUDPUQ&t=0s) but using ColorRamps set to your colours instead of Image Texture nodes, then keyframe the Value node to your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean the color of a specific material, the easiest way to do it might be to use the *RGB Input* node in a material and set it.  Here's a very trivial material:

[image: Material consisting of an RGB Input and Principled BSDF]

For your example, go to frame 0 and set the RGB Node to a nice red color.  Then hover over the color input of the RGB node and type <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe:

[image: RGB Input node showing where to hover]

Set the frame to 49 and do it again.

Set the frame to 50, pick your pink, and type <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe.

Set the frame to 74 and do it again.

Doe the same for gold using 85 and 94, and purple using 95-100.

If you want the colors to fade from one to the other, then don't add the keyframes at 49, 74, 84, or 94.